# File downloaded from PHP script is different than file on server

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a html file that allows a user to submit a file to  post a file to my 'upload_file.php' PHP script.

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>    
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php referenced above takes in a file, does some work, and spits out a xlsx file (using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)).  After creating the PHPExcel object, this is how I write it to the server and then force the user to download:

```
// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$fileBase = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
$outFilename = $fileBase[0] . date('His') . ".xlsx";
$objWriter->save($outFilename);
$url = "http://localhost/QWDATA/$outFilename";
//Initiate user download of file
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$outFilename\""); 
echo readfile($url);
```

When I do this, the download is initiated successfully... with one issue:

Opening the file that is downloaded results in an error in excel:

> "We found a problem with some content in $filename. Do you want us to
>   try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes."

Clicking "yes" on the excel error results in a 'repaired' xlsx file opening and looking exactly as one would expect.  Looking at a log of repairs that were done gives me this:

> error129480_02.xmlErrors
>   were detected in file
>   'C:\XPATHX\$filename.xlsx'Excel
>   completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this
>   workbook may have been repaired or
>   discarded.

... which is to say, nothing specific.

Tracking the issue back, opening the file directly from the server does NOT result in this error; telling me something additional is going on in the download code above.

My question is: What could be causing this and/or how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readfile` echoes by itself. You don't need to call echo.

Actually, doing so, will echo the result of readfile (which is the size of the file as an integer), so that causes a couple of extra bytes at the end of the file. This will be easy for Excel to fix, and probably won't result in actual data loss, but still the file is invalid, so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file on the server and the file that downloads, I noticed a 5 byte difference.

Having already removed all other `echo` commands from the php file due to suggestions here (https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/42854) and here ([PHPExcel File format or extension is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984132/phpexcel-file-format-or-extension-is-not-valid)) I knew *something* had to be adding information.

I made the following changes to the above code -- taking out the escaped quotes in the filename (just a personal guess) in the header setting and changing echo to readfile (as suggested here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm).  Thus giving me:

```
// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$fileBase = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
$outFilename = $fileBase[0] . date('His') . ".xlsx";
$objWriter->save($outFilename);
$url = "http://localhost/QWDATA/$outFilename";
//Initiate user download of file
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$outFilename"); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
readfile($outFilename);
```

This appears to directly download the file with no additions -- which means excel is happy and the problem is solved.

In short, it appears `echo readfile($outFilename);` needed to just be `readfile($outFilename);`